# Firebase push notification not working on Android 12

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Cloud Messaging (push notification) is not working on Android 12 devices, showing the following error in Log -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

It works if the app is running, but does not work if the app is not running. FirebaseMessagingService class has the following two lines of code -

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    }else {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution @Bhaskar Jyoti Dutta

Comment: No dear. Stillgetting the problem.